# Getting Cell data from SQL to combobox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My sql db has column names as (1,2,3,4 till 31) .. I do know that it isnt right to use numbers as column names.. but this is necessary ..

I have 2 cmbo boxes in my frnt end ;

```
namebox :which gets data from a name column ,
datebox: getting date column names.. (1,2,3.. 31 ).
```

with I want is.. when I change the selection in both boxes.. a txtbox should update values accrodingly..

example , this table;

```
Name 1    2    3    4 
abc  500  600  700 800
```

when selecting 1 from datebox and abc from name box I should get 500;
I tried inline query and got the desireed answer but it required hardcoding the datebox value.. select [1] from table where Name = 'abc';

How do I implement this via procedure ?

This is my procedure code :

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[getcelldata]
    @name varchar(50),@col varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @col from table where Name=@name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably with the help of a dynamic query like below

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[getcelldata]
    @name varchar(50),@col varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
declare @sql varchar(100);
set @sql  = 'SELECT [' + @col + '] from table where Name = '+ @name;    
exec (@sql);
END
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work.. , in C# i am supplying the value for col as datebox.SelectedValue , and it says that i am nt supplying value for col.. while executing the in sql.. it doesnt give the desired result

Comment: That's certain as procedure expects two parameter. You will need to pass twp parameter. Again, I just can't agree with you that it don't work, if you call the procedure like `exec getcelldata '1','abc'`; your `@sql` will become `select [1] from table where Name = 'abc'` which will surely work.

Comment: Yo... got it to work... was missing some quotes... Thanks.. :D